# Twitter Bootstrap Container background image not fitting in Firefox and Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this element as given below:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-body" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 100%), url('+contentService.backgroundUrl+')'}">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In this, the background image is fetched from a RESTful api asynchronously and rendered dynamically, hence the `contentService.backgroundUrl`.

The CSS for this is as given below:

```
.main-body {
    height: stretch;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This works as intended on Google Chrome and Safari. The intended effect is for this container to fill the viewport's full height in which the background image fits. However, Firefox and Microsoft Edge doesn't fill the full height of the viewport hence leaving a very large white section below the image.